# git fetch <remote-name> does nothing but, git fetch <remote-url> fetches the changes from remote

Tags: git, version-control

I have a remote repository locally on the same machine as my current working directory.

I am trying to fetch code from the remote repository (which is also on the same machine).

```
git remote add <remote-name> <remote-url>
git fetch <remote-name>
git merge <commit #>
```

This does not work, **$ git fetch** just returns without doing anything and **$ git merge <commit #>** says "not something that can be merged".

But, when I try to fetch directly using the remote URL:

```
git fetch <remote-path>
```

Git fetches code properly from the local-remote repository. and shows the following:

```
* branch                      HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

I am confused by this behaviour.

I have googled this kind of issue but could not find much. I must be missing something trivial. Please help.

**Edit:**

When I examined the branches in the remote repository (which is also on my local machine), it itself does not have any local branches. It only has upstream branches from where that remote was originally cloned. Is that the reason why **$ git fetch**  does not do anything.

Comment: After manually adding a remote, run `git config remote.<remote-name>.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/<remote_name>/*`. Replace `<remote_name>` with its real name. `git clone` automatically adds this config value for `remote.origin.fetch`.

Comment: @ElpieKay this did not help. When I fetch code using remote-url first. I am able to fetch using git fetch <remote-name> properly from next time onwards.